Getting cookie warnings on console, but cookie not being set
I'm trying to set a cookie on the browser (client side) after a user logs in. Both client and server are deployed on Vercel, where correct environment variables are set. This is the client call for logging in:
const onSubmit = async (values) => {
    setLoading(true);
    try {
      await axios
        .post(`${import.meta.env.VITE_SERVER_URL}/user/login`, {
          email: values.email,
          password: values.password,
        }, {
          withCredentials: true
        })
        .then((res) => {
          localStorage.setItem(
            "user-info",
            JSON.stringify(res.data.user)
          );
          setUser(res.data.user);
          toast({
            title: "Logged in successfully!",
            variant: "success",
          });
        });
    } catch (err) {
      toast({
        title: "Something went wrong!",
        description: err.response.data.message || "Try again",
        variant: "destructive",
      });
    } finally {
      setLoading(false);
    }
  };

on the server side I use this function to set cookie:
export const genTokenAndSetCookie = (userId, res) => {
  const token = jwt.sign({ userId }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
    expiresIn: "151d",
  });

  res.cookie("jwt", token, {
    httpOnly: true,
    maxAge: 151 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
    sameSite: "None",
    secure: true
  });

  return token;
};


When i test the login in production, on the console i get cookie warnings:
"Cookie “jwt” will soon be rejected because it is foreign and does not have the “Partitioned“ attribute."
indicating that im getting a cookie in response from the server. However, when i check the storage tab, I don't see the cookie being set.
I even tested my server response if it's setting cookies, both locally and the deployed url in Postman, and I'm getting a cookie back in response.
Why am I facing this problem?
EDIT: The cookies are being set in Chrome and the application works as intended. Does not work in Firefox though. Any fixes around that?

The waring only says that it will be rejected at some point in the future. Is there an actual problem with your application related to this cookie? Something not working regarding your login/authentication?

are you looking for the cookie in the correct domain?

@C3roe i use the cookie with other requests like creating or something like that, for authenticating the user. If the cookie is not set, I can't make those requests.

return res not token.
